# Expires Header with a .php output javascript

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-expires

I have creating a minify/obfusctor/gzip script in PHP of all my JS and CSS files but I can't expire but I have put this in my .htaccess:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2 hours"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2 hours"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2 hours"
Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"

<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|html|js|css)$">
    ExpiresDefault A7200
    Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(php|cgi|pl|htm)$">
    ExpiresActive Off
    Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

I want to expire all types *text/javascript* and *text/css* even if the extractor is a PHP file.

How can I do that?

Thx!

---

yes i put `header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8");`

Here is the entire HTTP Header :

```
Date: Sat, 20 Nov 2010 19:02:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.0
Content-Encoding: gzip
Last-Modified: Sat, 20 Nov 2010 16:03:24 GMT
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform
Content-Length: 181781
Pragma: no-cache
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8

200 OK
```

Comment: Do you specify the MIME media type of your output properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay resolved, i used mod_expires and i removed the Header append for PHP files.

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A1
ExpiresByType text/javascript A7200
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A7200

<FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
Header append Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private"
</FilesMatch>
```